# Git Bash prompt does not open - GIt bash installation

Tags: windows-8, installation, prompt, git-bash

I have installed several times the package GI-1.9.4-preview20140611.exe on my Windows 8. When I try to open the git bash command window, the window opens, but it is empty, no showing the usual welcome message and the git prompt. 
I have tried changing the command for the sh.exe file, which usually has the format 
"sh.exe --login -i" into just "sh.exe". The shell opens then, the PS1 variable shows only the sh.exe file name and version, nothing more. Is there something wrong with my installation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your installation is fine.

The git executable(sh.exe) for Command Line Tool is a script that in order to work will be based on the your windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe)

You will need the following string to refer to Git correctly as an executable:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"
```

Or you can always 'right-click' and SELECT 'Git Bash Here' or 'Git GUI Here'